# Spring Boot read values from application properties

Tags: java, spring

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but from what I got, is that I can use `@Value` annotations to read values from my `application.properties`.

As I figured out this works only for `Beans`.

I defined such a bean like this

```
@Service
public class DBConfigBean {


    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Bean
    public String getName() {
        return this.userName;
    }
}
```

When the application starts I'm able to retrieve the username, however - how can I access this value at runtime?

Whenever I do

`DBConfigBean conf = new DBConfigBean()
conf.getName();`

*** EDIT ***

Due to the comments I'm able to use this config DBConfigBean - but my initial problem still remains, when I want to use it in another class

```
@Configurable
public SomeOtherClass {

   @Autowired
   private DBConfigBean dbConfig; // IS NULL

   public void DoStuff() {
       // read the config value from dbConfig
   }
}
```

How can I read the DBConfig in a some helper class which I can define as a bean

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't instantiate your service with the new operator. You should inject it, for example

```
@Autowired
private DBConfigBean dbConfig;
```

and then `dbConfig.getName();`

Also you don't need any `@Bean` decorator in your `getName()` method

You just need to tell spring where to search for your annotated beans. So in your configuration you could add the following:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"a.package.containing.the.service",
                             "another.package.containing.the.service"})
```

### EDIT

The `@Value`, `@Autowired` etc annotations can only work with beans, that spring is aware of.

Declare your `SomeOtherClass` as a bean and add the package config in your @Configuration class

```
@Bean
private SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;
```

and then

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"a.package.containing.the.service"              
  "some.other.class.package"})
 public class AppConfiguration {

  //By the way you can also define beans like:
   @Bean 
   public AwesomeService service() {
       return new AwesomeService();
   }

 }
```

Comment: That works , but I want to use it on a class which is not a bean because it needs to get instantiated - like a ManagerClass. How does this work in that case?

Comment: Dependency injection only works with beans. What prevents you declaring the ManagerClass as a bean?

Comment: Basically just the fact that I'm not getting it to work. 
when using ```@Configurable ```on ```AbstractDBManager ``` my ```@Autowired
    private DBConfigBean dbConfig;``` is null

Comment: Just add the bean annotation @Bean private DbManager manager. Then do not forget to add the package of the DbManager to your ComponentScan packages

Comment: sorry today is my first day with spring boot - I'm not getting it without an example

Comment: not a problem, I updated the answer. But as @SimonMartinelli suggested, you should check the docs. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 3):

As Eirini already mentioned you must inject your beans.

The @Value annotation only works on Spring beans.

There is another way of accessing configuration with @ConfigurationProperties.
There you define a class that holds the configuration. 
The main advantage is, that this is typesafe and the configuration is in one place.

Read more about this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your DBConfig with @Component annotation and inject it using @Autowired :

```
@Autowired
private DBConfig dbConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below annotation to your DBConfigBean class:

@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})